# Build a Visual Studio solution on a target macOS machine remotely

Tags: c++, macos, visual-studio, cmake, cross-platform

We have a large Visual Studio C++ solution that builds on a Windows machine.
We want to build this application on a macOS system and I’ve [read](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/cppblog/visual-studio-for-remote-macos-c-development/) that it’s possible by building/deploying remotely to a target macOS machine from a Windows Visual Studio environment.

Can we do that if we have a Visual studio solution with MSBuild projects? Or it is mandatory to have CMake projects to do that? At least for Linux remote building it seems that [CMake isn't mandatory](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/build-solution-under-remote-linux-from-windows-wit/908804).

We also need to build our application in a CI/CD pipeline so we also need to build from a command line, from what I understood I also [read](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/linux/connectionmanager-reference?view=msvc-170&viewFallbackFrom=vs-2019) that it should be possible but I don't know how maintainable it is.

Comment: I don't believe that Visual Studio for Mac is a) the same thing on Mac; I believe it's rebraanded Xamarin, and b) Visual Studio for Mac does not support C++. You'll want a platform-agnostic build system. I could be way off base. Maybe edit your question with the resource you're citing?

Comment: Needs to be cmake i think https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/events/pure-virtual-cpp-2022/targeting-macos-from-visual-studio

Comment: @sweenish I'm not talking about Visual Studio for Mac (that covers only .NET projects), I've added some references to the topic.

Comment: Your first link makes it pretty clear that you need cmake.

Comment: It seems that cmake [isn't always mandatory](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/build-solution-under-remote-linux-from-windows-wit/908804) at least for Linux remote building, I was wondering if something similar existed for macOS remote building.

Comment: Currently macOS msbuild does not support C++. You need to use third-party software.

Comment: I don't want to build a C++ project by using Visual Studio on macOS, I already said that. Is anyone reading the question I asked?

Comment: I noticed a similar thread in the [Developer Community](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/Build-a-Visual-Studio-solution-on-a-targ/10220145?q=Build+a+Visual+Studio+solution+on+a+target+macOS+machine+remotely)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For anyone interested, **it is possible to remote build on Linux/macOS a MSBuild project** without converting it to a CMake project.

Follow [this topic](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/Build-a-Visual-Studio-solution-on-a-targ/10220145?viewtype=all) for more info.